# How correctly delete storage file?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

In my Windows Store App I have some files(images) in my storage folder.

Then, when I want to use image I create bitmap like this:

```
BitmapImage BitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("full_file_path"));
```

And my `Image` control has `ImageSource = "{Binding Path=BitmapImage}"`. 
All works great. But when I want to delete my file, I use:

```
BitmapImage = null;
```

and then:

```
  try
  {
        await storageFile.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.Default);
  }
  catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
  {
        // and I get exception here.
  }
```

Question: How I should correctly delete file?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to delete the image file that you loaded. The file remains locked until the Image is disposed. In my opinion i think you should copy the image after you've loaded it, and use that copy of image in your Image Control

You can use following code to for your scenario without even bothering about disposing image before delete,

```
BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
bmpImage.BeginInit();
Uri uri = new Uri(filePath,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
bmpImage.UriSource = uri;
bmpImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bmpImage.EndInit();
```

See if it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, but  I think windows store app not support System.Windows.Media.Imaging (the use Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;)